# How do I update UI when location changes occur?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a navigation bar that is at the top of my web app. That nav bar has tabs for which location you are at. (I.E. 'home' = '/home', 'settings' = '/settings' etc.) How can I update the UI to denote which tab they are on after the URL change has occurred?

To determine routes in the app the code is:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).
    when('/projects', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html',
      controller: 'projectsCtrl'
    }).
    when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
      controller: 'aboutCtrl'
    }).
    when('/contact', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
      controller: 'contactCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: That depends on what your code looks like. Can you update your question to include the navigation code?

Comment: When this was a Jekyll app the following code did what I want to accomplish:

    `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      var segments = location.href.split("/");
      var tab = segments[segments.length - 1];
      if (tab === 'contact') {
        $('#contact').addClass('active');
      } else if (tab === 'about') {
        $('#about').addClass('active');
      } else if (tab === 'projects') {
        $('#projects').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $('#home').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  </script>`

Comment: Please the code in your comment in the question itself. (e.g. "I'm trying to recreate the following behavior, but using Angular routes instead of jQuery: ...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want a quick implementation i might recommend putting something like {{title}} in your html template, and configuring and using $rootScope.title to update this value from each of your controllers.

implementation would be something like this plus the update to your template.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.title = "";
})
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.title = "Navigation Bar Title"
})
```

but i think that a better way to do it would actually be to create a state for your navigation bar and make each of your current states a different child state of your navigation state.  Because of scope inheritance you would have access to the navigation states $scope.title in any nested child state.

here is a good place to learn how that should work.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-custom-data